OpenFOAM API: Access constructed matrix
I am interested in leveraging OpenFOAM to conduct data assimilation studies using 4DVar.
I already have CFD data, and I have synthetic measurement data. All I need to be able to do is to call OpenFOAM from my own program to construct the system of equations so that I can run my 4DVar routine.
I am intending to do this either in Python or C++.
How do I do this? Is one language more amendable to interfacing with OpenFOAM than another?
Thank you

I think this is a question best asked on the OpenFOAM forums.
